# Miners stop working in Azure consortium blockchain

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, microsoft-azure

I had setup Blockchain on Azure (BaaS) few months ago, Its working fine till few days before,

but now I am facing issue with my transaction, after debugging I found that my transactions are not getting any response from blockchain,

I checked admin portal where I found All the miners Have stopped working
[image]

I have also checked all the VM's are running

Any one knows How to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into same issue more than once. Stopping all the miners and starting them again does the trick.
But I do not know why this happens!

Comment: how to start them?? I have tried restarting the VM's dose not make any difference.

Comment: I think it should be relatively easier, there is an option to "Stop" the VM's.
Stop all VM's and then choose the option "Start" on your VM's

Comment: After restarting <or shutdown and start>, It will run for some minutes and stop working again when lastblock number of mining node and transaction node were too different.

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar problem. And restarting the vm didn't worked.

My solution was to reimage the VM that wasn't working. But I suppose redeploying can do the trick also.

Because I just reimage one of the nodes, the ethereum network keep the same.